# Control template make fancy button

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I want to make special shape for button with control template or with stmth another. Now my button looks like this but in fact there are three buttons not one. So I want to make for them one trigger like Mouse Over. But Idk how to make it ..

```
<Window x:Class="ExamWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExamWpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="Buttons" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Background="Black">
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="fancyButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Name="Border" Background="RoyalBlue" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" TextBlock.Foreground="White" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"></ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="DarkBlue"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="fancyButtonL" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Name="Border" Background="RoyalBlue" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,2,0,2" TextBlock.Foreground="White" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"></ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="DarkBlue"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="fancyButtonR" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Name="Border" Background="RoyalBlue" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,2,2,2" TextBlock.Foreground="White" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold">
                <Grid>

                    <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"></ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="DarkBlue"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <Button Template="{StaticResource fancyButton}"   Padding="105,10" Content="Regular button" Canvas.Left="225" Canvas.Top="37"/>
            <Button Template="{StaticResource fancyButtonL}"  BorderThickness="3" Padding="10" Content="Regular button" Canvas.Left="214" Canvas.Top="45" Height="18" Width="13"/>
            <Button Template="{StaticResource fancyButtonR}"  BorderThickness="3" Padding="10" Content="Regular button" Canvas.Left="522" Canvas.Top="45" Height="18" Width="13"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGPhZ.jpg)

Comment: You should use same static resource for each button if the resource template is same. You have create 3 copies of same resource. In static resource simply use fancybutton for each button resource and delete other 2.

Comment: The border thickness in each button is different just use it in directly after canvas.top (at end) inside grid for each button.